# How to detect if current site is in virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, virtual-directory

I have a website, which on DEV env. I use virtual directory, while in LIVE env. I don't.
I want to distinguish between virtual directory & none virtual, in runtime.

How can I acheive this?

Thanks!

Comment: my website on DEV computer is http://dev/something/index.aspx, while on live its just http://live/index.aspx. I want to distinguish whether i'm on virtual directory or not

Comment: I do this with a custom key in my web.config so i do not rely on infrastructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Web tab in Project Properties and change `Virtual path` to `/`.
This will make the debugging server use the root.

To answer the question, you're looking for the `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath`, which gets the virtual path to the application root.

Answer (score -1):

Simply do like...

```
    if (Request.IsLocal) // Will return true on localhost 
    {

    }
    else
    {
        // Request is from Virtual Directory
    }
```

Comment: My DEV computer is not nesseceraliy localhost. I want to know if the website resides on virtual directory, or on the ROOT dir